# Add a condition to my copy and paste from one sheet to another based on matching dates

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new at VBA and am stuck and would like some help. I need a code with a condition to  match the date in cell(J1) in sheet1 ("Exec Summary") to a range of dates (A3:A60) in sheet2("Monthly comments") and if the condition is met to copy the rows of data in cells "S3:S30" in sheet1("Exec Summary") and paste a transpose version of the data to sheet2 where the date matched.

At the moment I have a button and this contains a code which copies the commentary section (Cell S) in my sheet 1 "Exec Summary" and pastes a transpose of that comment section from "Exec Summary" into the other sheet "Monthly comments" if the row is empty. If there is anyway to adjust this so that it has a condition of when the date in a cell in "Exec Summary" sheet matches the date in a given set of the "Monthly Comment" Sheet then it will paste the transpose data will be preferred.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Sheets("Monthly Comments")
        .Cells(.Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3).Resize(1, 30).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets("Exec Summary").Range("S3:S32").Value)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i as integer: i = 0
    With Sheets("Monthly Comments")  
        i = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Exec Summary").Range("J1").Value2, .Range("A2:A60"), 0)
        if i > 0 then
            .Cells(i, 3).Resize(1, 30).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets("Exec Summary").Range("S3:S32").Value)
        end if
    End With
End Sub
```

This code try to find a match of the date at `J1` in `S3:S30`. If it found any then you copy & paste

Comment: Thanks for helping, but the data S3:S30 is all data for the cell date J1 and that J1 Cell has to match the dates in the other sheet Monthly Comments A2:A60 and when the condition is met the S3:S30 rows are transposed pasted into the Monthly Comments Sheet starting in cell C.

Comment: Change range from `S3:S30` to `A2:A60` ( already updated in code above )

Comment: Hey sorry I get a run time error of 1004, unable to get the Match Property of the Worksheetfunction class

Comment: The code runs and no error pops up, but nothing happens.

Comment: type error: we don't have `x`, we have `i` ( updated code )

Comment: so the code works, but it just pastes into the next available row in the Monthly Comment Sheet and not paste in the row  where the date is matching, which is what Im looking for, any ideas? and thanks for cooperating this is really tedious.

Comment: Let say you want to paste to the `C` row of the matching date ( updated code )

Comment: So I get a runtime error 5, Invalid procedure call or argument